# solve the initial value problem $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{ |y|}$, 0<y<10 and $y(0)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{ |y|},0<y<10$ and $y(0)=0$.  I see that $\sqrt{ |y|}$ is continuous and has a partial derivative w.r.to. y exist and bounded in the given domain. So the ivp has a unique solution but the answer is infinite.

Comment: How can $0<y$ but at the same time $y(0)=0$?

Comment: @Arthur Maybe $0<x<10$ was meant?

Comment: @ Arthur I think u r right (0,0) is not an interior pt of the given domain.

Comment: In what sense is $\frac1{2\sqrt{|y|}}$ bounded around $y=0$?

Answer (score 0):

How about $y=x^2$?

I got to it just by looking. I ignored the absolute value and thought about polynomials: the square root halve the degree. Differentiation reduce the degree by $1$. If the degree happens to be $2$, then those two things are the same. Of course, $y=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: I think you meant $x^2/4$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard problem to show the difference of the Peano and Picard-Lindelöf theorems. The general solution is
$$
y(x)=\frac14(x-c)_+^2=\begin{cases}0&0\le x<c\\\frac14(x-c)^2&c\le x\end{cases}
$$
Numerically you get a solution differently from the zero function if you add some small noise in each integration step.

Comment: But the pt (0,0) is not an interior pt of the domain.

Comment: Then how do you explain the initial condition $y(0)=0$?

Comment: i alsp confuse about the question